# Simple bank OOP structure in PHP

Tags: beginner, php, object-oriented, design-patterns

I don't have much experience using either OOP or PHP since this is probably my first thing ever written in this language. I've had some exposure to OOP but I'm not used to writing programs that way. I would greatly appreciate some feedback concerning OOP and PHP best practices, clean code, and overall design. I'm also curious if my code could make use of some design patterns.

It's supposed to be a blueprint for bank simulator app. For now, It has the following capabilities:

- Client classes - NaturalPerson and Company. Client can have multiple bank accounts as well as open new and delete current ones.
- Account class - it stores an instance of Client, amount of money and transactions history. Using an instance of that class, a client can deposit money to an account, withdraw money and make a transfer to another account. Every operation is saved the **history** array.
- Log classes - AccountOperationLog and TransferLog. Every instance stores details of a operation made by an account.

.

```
namespace Bank;

abstract class Client
{
  protected $numMoney;
  protected $accounts = [];

  public function __construct($numMoney)
  {
    $this->numMoney = $numMoney; 
  }

  public function addNumMoney($ammount)
  {
    $this->numMoney += $ammount;
  }

  public function substractNumMoney($ammount)
  {
    $this->numMoney -= $ammount;
  }

  public function getNumMoney() : float
  {
    return $this->numMoney;
  }

  public function openNewAccount($name)
  {
    $newAccount = new Account($this, $name);
    array_push($this->accounts, $newAccount);
  }

  public function closeAccount($account)
  {
    if (in_array($account, $this->accounts)) {
      $account->withdrawMoney($account->getNumMoney());
      $this->deleteFromAccounts($account);
    }
  }

  private function deleteFromAccounts($account)
  {
    if (in_array($account, $this->accounts)) {
      unset($this->accounts[array_search($account, $this->accounts)]);
    }
  }

  public function getAccount($name) : Account
  {
    foreach ($this->accounts as $account) {
      if ($account->getName() === $name) {
        return $account;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

}

class Company extends Client
{
  private $name;
  private $ein;

  public function __construct($name, $ein, $numMoney)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->ein = $ein;
    parent::__construct($numMoney);
  }

  public function getName() : string
  {
   return $this->name;
  }
}

class NaturalPerson extends Client
{
  private $firstName;
  private $lastName;
  private $ssn;

  public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $ssn, $numMoney)
  {
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
    $this->ssn = $ssn;
    parent::__construct($numMoney);
  }

  public function getName() : string
  {
   return $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName;
  }

}

class Account
{
  private $client;
  private $name;
  private $numMoney = 0;
  private $debt;
  private $history = [];

  public function __construct($client, $name)
  {
    $this->client = $client;
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function getName() : string
  {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function getNumMoney() : float
  {
    return $this->numMoney;
  }

  public function getHistory() : array
  {
    return $this->history;
  }

  public function addNumMoney($ammount)
  {
    $this->numMoney += $ammount;
  }

  public function substractNumMoney($ammount)
  {
    $this->numMoney -= $ammount;
  }

  public function depositMoney($ammount)
  {
    if ($this->client->getNumMoney() < $ammount) {
      return;
    }

    $this->addNumMoney($ammount);
    $this->client->substractNumMoney($ammount);

    $this->addAccountOperationLogToHistory('Deposition', 'Today', $ammount, $this->numMoney);
  }

  public function withdrawMoney($ammount)
  {
    if ($this->numMoney < $ammount) {
      return;
    }
    $this->substractNumMoney($ammount);
    $this->client->addNumMoney($ammount);

    $this->addAccountOperationLogToHistory('Withdraw', 'Today', $ammount, $this->numMoney);
  }

  public function addAccountOperationLogToHistory($type, $date, $ammount, $moneyAfter)
  {
    $operationLog = new AccountOperationLog(...func_get_args());
    array_push($this->history, $operationLog);
  }

  public function addTransferLogToHistory($type, $name, $date, $ammount, $moneyAfter, $sender, $beneficiary)
  {
    $operationLog = new TransferLog(...func_get_args());
    array_push($this->history, $operationLog);
  }

  public function transferMoney($account, $title, $ammount)
  {
    if ($this->numMoney < $ammount) {
      return;
    }

    $this->substractNumMoney($ammount);
    $account->addNumMoney($ammount);

    $this->addTransferLogToHistory('Transfer', $title, 'today', $ammount, $this->numMoney, $account->client->getName(), $this->client->getName());
    $account->addTransferLogToHistory('Transfer', $title, 'today', $ammount, $account->getNumMoney(), $this->client->getName(), $account->client->getName());

  }

}

class AccountOperationLog
{
  private $type;
  private $date;
  private $ammount;
  private $numMoneyAfter;

  public function __construct($type, $date, $ammount, $numMoneyAfter)
  {
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->date = $date;
    $this->ammount = $ammount;
    $this->numMoneyAfter = $numMoneyAfter;
  }

  private function saveToDB()
  {
    // Implement later
  }
}

class TransferLog extends AccountOperationLog
{
  private $title;
  private $sender;
  private $beneficiary;

  public function __construct($type, $title, $date, $ammount, $numMoneyAfter, $sender, $beneficiary)
  {
    parent::__construct($type, $date, $ammount, $numMoneyAfter);
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->sender = $sender;
    $this->beneficiary = $beneficiary;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you include the specification? As in, what problem does this code solve?

Comment: I fixed my post, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Much appreciated :-)

Comment: Why does `Client` have money as well? At first I thought it was a method to sum money from all `Accounts`. But it seems you can store money in both `Client` and `Account` separately.

Comment: I figured that a client has to have money in the first place to deposit it in the bank, so it's like cash.

Comment: Maybe I don’t fully understand your class hierarchy by now, but couldn’t be cash in an `Account` of type `privateLocker` and the `Client` could have a method `deposit($amount, $account)`?

Comment: you probably want to take rounding into account, float math always winds up with rounding errors. One solution is to convert everything to cents within the class, and back to a float (using sprintf) when you get the value back out. That way you would only be dealing with integer math